# Macbook Pro renders font differently then other screen

Tags: font

This is the font looks on my friend's Macbook Pro:
[image]

This is the font looks on my computer with DELL U2412M monitor:
[image]

They look different, the first one looks smooth and the second one looks blurry.

Anyone have insight on this?

Comment: How old is the Macbook Pro? Does it has a retina display? This means it will be way smoother then the monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macbook Pro might have a retina display, that's why it's smoother then the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

It looks different because your Macbook and the Dell does not get the same resolution. Your Macbook should display 1280*800 or 2560 x 1600 or other, and the Dell displays 1900*1200. The ratio is not the same, it has to be stretched.